# Constrain image size to max height and max width according to aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, image, math

I've a function called `getMediaSize` that accepts a image height and image width:

```js
const MAX_HEIGHT = 500
const MAX_WIDTH = 600
function getMediaSize(iw, ih) {

}
```

I'd like the function to return the new image width and height that fits the `MAX_WIDTH x MAX_HEIGHT` dimensions according to the aspect ratio.

For example, `getMediaSize(1200, 800)` should return `{ w: 600, h: 400 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at each dimension individually, its simple to see the math for adjustment.

```
MAX_DIMENSION = CURRENT_DIMENSION * ADJUSTMENT

// We need to figure out what the adjustment is, we have the other two values
// do some algebra and we get
ADJUSTMENT = MAX_DIMENSION / CURRENT_DIMENSION
```

The problem that arises is each dimension is going to have its own adjustment value which results in a stretched/compressed image (the aspect ration does not stay the same). So we need to pick just one of the adjustment values to use, but which one? The smallest of course, otherwise one of the dimensions will overflow.

```
// Calculate which adjustment is the smallest, width or height
// otherwise we'd overflow one of them.
let widthPercent = MAX_WIDTH / iw;
let heightPercent = MAX_HEIGHT / ih;
let smallestPercent = Math.min(widthPercent, heightPercent);

// This works for both scaling up and scaling down
return {
    w: iw * smallestPercent,
    h: ih * smallestPercent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example
https://codepen.io/Kison/pen/JjdaMda

And here is source code

```js
const MAX_HEIGHT = 500;
const MAX_WIDTH = 600;

function getMediaSize(iw, ih) {
  let 
    ratio = 0,
    height = ih,
    width = iw
  ;  

  if (iw > MAX_WIDTH && iw > ih) 
  {   
      height = MAX_WIDTH / (iw / ih /* aspect ratio */);
      width = MAX_WIDTH;
  } 
  else if (ih > MAX_HEIGHT && ih > iw) 
  {    
      width = MAX_HEIGHT / (ih / iw /* aspect ratio */);
      height = MAX_HEIGHT;
  }

  return {
    width: Math.round(width),
    height: Math.round(height)
  }
}
```

Comment: Case when width == height is not handled properly.

Comment: @andrzej1_1, probably you are right. I would be really happy to see your solution with filled gap.